# Insert data with Sqlite in swift and i have the same value in two columns

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, sqlite

I have one problem with swift when i use Sqlite.
I have four columns in my table and i try to insert value.

Sqlite put same value of the columns nom and columns prenom.
I can't find the why.
My viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    afficherCheminApplication()

    if let bd = ouvrirBaseSqlLite() {
        insererPersonne(nom: "Perrin", prenom: "David", age: "36", db: bd)
    }
}
```

My fonction to create database
I think this is right ?

```
func ouvrirBaseSqlLite() -> OpaquePointer? {

    var db: OpaquePointer? = nil

    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("ExempleBd.sqlite")

    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {

        print("Erreur lors de l'ouverture de la base de données !")
        return nil
    }

    if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Personne (idPersonne INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \n"
                        + "nom varchar, \n"
                        + "prenom varchar, \n "
                        + "age INTEGER)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {

        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
        return nil
    }

    print("Connection bd réussie")

    return db
}
```

My function ton insert values into database
I don't no why when i open the database i have "David" in the columns nom and to "David" in the columns prenom

```
func insererPersonne(nom xNom : String, prenom xPrenom : String, age xAge : String, db : OpaquePointer) {

    if xNom.count < 4, xPrenom.count < 4,
        xAge.count < 1, xAge.count > 3 {
        return
    }

    var stmt: OpaquePointer?

    let queryString = "INSERT INTO Personne (nom, prenom, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
    //let queryString = "INSERT INTO Personne (nom, prenom, age) VALUES ('Perrin', 'Dave', 33);"

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("Erreur lors de la preparation du insert : \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, xNom.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8), -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("Erreur lors de la creation du nom : \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, xPrenom.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8), -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("Erreur lors de la creation du prenom : \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3, (xAge as NSString).intValue) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("Erreur lors de la creation de l'âge : \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("Erreur lors de l'insertion de la nouvelle personne : \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
}
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the same value in both columns? Are you looking at the table data using the `sqlite3` command line tool or are you seeing the duplicate values after your code queries the data from the table? Maybe your problem is when how you access the data after storing it.

Comment: I have open the database with "Datum Free".